# How to handle \n or \r or \r\n in json Schema validation?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I used regex to escape tags like <> or  it working fine but i want to allow \n, \r or \r\n in my description.I am getting description from email hence it contain to many such character.

```
eg: (Description)"You get solution\n on stack\roverflow"

    "StringRegex": {
                "anyOf": [{
                    "type": "null"
                }, {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "^(?:(?!<.*?>).)*$"

                }]
            }
    Error: 
    {
                "ObjectKey": "[0].",
                "Message": "should match pattern \"^(?:(?!<.*?>).)*$\""
            }
```

Comment: Probably, `"^(?:(?!<[^<>]*>)[\\s\\S])*$"`? Or `"^(?:(?!<[^<>]*>)[\s\S])*$"`?

Comment: Thank you friend @WiktorStribiżew .

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew ,

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew , I make one file that contain **regex**, i refer these file in json schema at different location using **$ref**(file: **RegexSchema.json**) . Is it good or ok? OR another option is write regex in each schema level using **PATTERN**. (Which one is good ? , If we consider **speed?**)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks ,

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, did either of the regexes work for you? Shall I post an answer?